Unable to read PDF file and extract text
def input_pdf_text(uploaded_file):
    # Open the PDF file in binary mode
    with uploaded_file as file:

        # Create a PdfReader object to read the PDF

        reader = pdf.PdfReader(file)

        text=""
# Loop through each page and extract text

        for page in reader(len(reader.pages)):

            page=reader.pages[page]

            text+= str(page.extract_text())

        return text
# It is suppose to read the uploaded file and extract text


There are syntax errors and formatting issues in the loop where you iterate over the pages and a misuse of reader(len(reader.pages)): were the syntax is incorrect for looping through pages.
Install PyPDF2 using pip:
pip install PyPDF2

then here you have a code sample
import PyPDF2
def input_pdf_text(uploaded_file):
    # Ensure the file is opened in binary mode if it isn't already
    if uploaded_file.mode != 'rb':
        uploaded_file = open(uploaded_file, 'rb')

    # Create a PdfReader object to read the PDF
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(uploaded_file)
    text = ""

    # Loop through each page and extract text
    for page in reader.pages:
        # Extract text from each page and concatenate it
        if page.extract_text():
            text += page.extract_text()

    # Close the file if opened
    if uploaded_file.mode == 'rb':
        uploaded_file.close()

    return text

to use it, just:
# Example of using the function with a file path
file_path = 'path_to_your_pdf_file.pdf'
with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
    pdf_text = input_pdf_text(file)
print(pdf_text)


PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf
